# Dropdown values being reset to initial value upon submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have used the following code to insert the selected item from dropdownlist into the sql database table. It runs, but the selected item for dropdownlist 1, 2, 5 and 6 always stores the first item in the dropdown list.
Here's my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        //populate gridview
        TextBox2.Focus();
        string selectquery = "select [TASK ID],[NATURE OF PAYMENT],[DESC],FREQUENCY,PREALERT1,PREALERT2,OWNER,[VERIFICATION OWNER],(case when STATUS='1' then 'Active' when STATUS='0' then 'Inactive' ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END)as STATUS,ID from Compliance_Tracker.dbo.tasklistManager;";
        obj6.PopulateGrid(GridView1, selectquery);
    }
    {
        // populate dropdownlist for prealert 1
        for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
        {
            DropDownList3.Items.Insert(i, new ListItem((i + 1).ToString(), (i + 1).ToString()));
        }
        DropDownList3.DataBind();
    }
    {
        // populate dropdown list for prealert 2
        for (int j = 0; j <= 30; j++)
        {
            DropDownList4.Items.Insert(j, new ListItem((j + 1).ToString(), (j + 1).ToString()));
        }
        DropDownList4.DataBind();
    }
    {
        //populate dropdown for Nature of Payment
        string query = "select * from Compliance_Tracker.dbo.paymentNatureMaster where STATUS='1';";
        string columnname = "DESC";
        string datavaluefield="DESC";
        obj6.PopulateCombo(DropDownList1,query,columnname,datavaluefield);
    }
    {
        //populate dropdown for frequency
        string query1 = "select * from Compliance_Tracker.dbo.frequencyMaster where STATUS='1';";
        string columnname1 = "DESC";
        string datavaluefield1 = "DESC";
        obj6.PopulateCombo(DropDownList2,query1, columnname1,datavaluefield1);
    }
    {
        //populate dropdown for owner
        string query2 = "select * from Compliance_Tracker.dbo.ownerMaster where STATUS='1';";
        string columnname2 = "NAME";
        string datavaluefield2 = "NAME";
        obj6.PopulateCombo( DropDownList5,query2, columnname2,datavaluefield2);
    }
    {
        //populate dropdown for owner verification
        string query3 = "select * from Compliance_Tracker.dbo.verificationMaster where STATUS='1'";
        string columnname3 = "NAME";
        string datavaluefield3 = "NAME";
        obj6.PopulateCombo(DropDownList6,query3, columnname3,datavaluefield3);
    }
```

mybutton click event sorry i forgot to add the main thing

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "insert into Compliance_Tracker.dbo.tasklistManager([NATURE OF PAYMENT],[DESC],FREQUENCY,PREALERT1,PREALERT2,OWNER,[VERIFICATION OWNER],STATUS)values('" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList6.SelectedItem.Text + "','" + DropDownList7.SelectedValue + "');";
    obj6.ExecuteScalar(query);
    string selectquery = "select [TASK ID],[NATURE OF PAYMENT],[DESC],FREQUENCY,PREALERT1,PREALERT2,OWNER,[VERIFICATION OWNER],(case when STATUS='1' then 'Active' when STATUS='0' then 'Inactive' ELSE 'UNKNOWN' END)as STATUS,ID from Compliance_Tracker.dbo.tasklistManager;";
    obj6.PopulateGrid(GridView1, selectquery);
    TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    DropDownList7.SelectedItem.Text = "Active";
}
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e) { }
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e) { }
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) { }
protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e) { }
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) { }
```

}

this is my html code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/LoggedInMasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TaskList.aspx.cs" Inherits="TaskList" %>
```

## TASKLIST MANAGER TABLE

```
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TASK ID" SortExpression="TASK ID" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="TASKID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[TASK ID]") %>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>

       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NATURE OF PAYMENT" SortExpression="NATURE OF PAYMENT" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="NOP" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[NATURE OF PAYMENT]") %>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownnop"></asp:DropDownList>
           </EditItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DESC" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DESC" Text='<%#Eval("[DESC]") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID ="DESC" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("[DESC]") %>'></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="REQUIREDFIELDVALIDATORDESC" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DESC" ErrorMessage="FIELD CANNOT BE EMPTY"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FREQUENCY" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="FREQUENCY" Text='<%#Eval("FREQUENCY") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownfreq"></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DUE DATE OF PAYMENT" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DDOP" Text='<%#Eval("PREALERT1") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownddop"></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DUE DATE OF SUBMISSION OF RETURN" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="DDOSOR" Text='<%#Eval("PREALERT2") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownddosor"></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OWNER" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="OWNER" Text='<%#Eval("OWNER") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownowner"></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VERIFICATION OWNER" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="VO" Text='<%#Eval("[VERIFICATION OWNER]") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropdownvo"></asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STATUS" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
          <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label runat="server" ID="STATUS" Text='<%#Eval("STATUS") %>'/>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList runat ="server" ID="dropdownstatus">
              <asp:ListItem Text="Active" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
              <asp:ListItem Text="Inactive" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
              </asp:DropDownList>
          </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ID" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-BackColor="DarkGreen" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
         <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" />
         </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update" />
         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" />
         </EditItemTemplate> 
         </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NumericFirstLast" PageButtonCount="4" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

and here's my populatecombo code

```
 public bool PopulateCombo(DropDownList DDList, string strSQL, string DisMember, string ValMember)
    {
        SqlDataAdapter DAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet DSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                Conn.Open();
            DAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, Conn);
            DAdpt.Fill(DSet);
            DDList.DataSource = DSet.Tables[0];
            DDList.DataTextField = DisMember;
            DDList.DataValueField = ValMember;
            DDList.DataBind();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            //return null;
            throw new Exception(Ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            DAdpt.Dispose();
            DSet.Dispose();
            Conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

here is my executescalar function

```
 public object ExecuteScalar(string strSQL)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                Conn.Open();
            Comm = new SqlCommand(strSQL, Conn);
            return Comm.ExecuteScalar();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            //return null;
            throw new Exception(Ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Comm.Dispose();
            Conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you changing the SelectedItem of these dropdownlists anywhere else? Do they have SelectedIndexChanged event?

Comment: nope .. I don't change them anywhere else

Comment: I hope you understand my problem

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on the button click event and inspecting your values once it fires?

Comment: My problem is that Iam always getting the lowest indexed item of the dropdownlist items even though I select any other item of the dropdownlist during the entry process into the table

Comment: Yes, @Tanner . I saw by putting the breakpoint and the values coming were the lowest indexed only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's an issue in your `Page_Load`. You have check for `if(!IsPostBack)`, and you have some code in braces after that:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    //populate gridview
    ....
}
```

But then the rest of the code is in braces after this initial block, so it will get fired each time you post back, therefore resetting the lists. All of the code should be in that first set of braces and you can remove all of the extra braces around the other blocks that bind the dropdowns:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    //populate gridview
    ....

    // populate dropdownlist for prealert 1
    ...

    // populate dropdown list for prealert 2
    ...

    //populate dropdown for Nature of Payment
    ...

    //populate dropdown for frequency
    ...

    //populate dropdown for owner
    ...

    //populate dropdown for owner verification        
    ...
}
```

If you put a breakpoint in the page load as it currently is, you should see that when you submit, it will reload each dropdown and set it's value to the initial value again.

Comment: sorry, to ask such a foolish question

Comment: @user3789152 we all have bad days

Comment: yes... seriously you can see that by the length of my code and with such a silly mistake just ate up an hour of mine

Comment: I can't ... even if I want to

Comment: I think there's a 15 rep limit on voting

Comment: just take a look at my rep ,I joined just yesterday